# Is there a way to upload a virus to find out what it does?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is there anywhere on the stackexchange network we can upload a (new) virus to have it analyzed? I just received an extremely legitimate looking email which had a link to a `.zip` file which had contained a `.vbs` and the source code is obfuscated. (the only way I caught it was the domain hosting the download was something shady). Is there any other places I could look for more information or post the vbs source? I am wondering if this was a targeted attack as the email new information about me.

Answer (score 2):

You want the code de-obfuscated? And then reviewed to give you a summary? I'm afraid there is no such StackExchange site for that.

Answer (score 0):

VirusTotal - https://www.virustotal.com/ allows you to upload malware samples which are scanned using many different AV scanning engines so you can identify the strain of malware. On the results page it also gives some info about the samples that are analysed.